# Who cleans everything?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Humans are carbon-based cellular lifeforms, and as such we tend to leave disgusting residue on all surfaces after a while. And I'm sure someone's spilled a few bottles of synthehol at the lounge. And yet, the Enterprise always seems clean.

So who or what cleans this stuff up?

From CGPgrey via the HI podcast.

Comment: The adventures of the Enterprise janitorial staff are truly the stuff of legend. Heck, [Quark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_%28TV_series%29) and [Hyperdrive](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0481449/) are based on the premise.

Comment: Red shirts double as janitorial and maintenance staff. That's why, whenever you see the ship attacked and a bunch of them are sucked into space, the ship interior is shown to be trashed in the shots that follow. Especially the engine room, because starfleet engineers usually just leave smoking broken hardware lying around instead of disposing of it properly.

Comment: In TNG [Up the Long Ladder](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/144.htm) Riker suggests that the ship cleans itself. How exactly that is done isn't elaborated on. `RIKER: That isn't necessary. The ship will clean itself.`

Comment: Cleaning in Quark's bar was done manually. During the occupation this was done by Bajorans. During the show this was probably done by Rom, Nog and the other Ferengi staff.

Comment: [Roger Wilco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Quest)?

Comment: Janitors don't get paid. Humans in the 23rd Century have learned to progress beyond such things. There are just some people for whom janitorial labor is a passion. The same people who play games like Viscera Cleanup Detail or Truck Simulator today and pay for the privilege. </troll>

Comment: Skutters. At one time there were many, but 3 million years took its toll. There are a pitiful few left.